# How to add Global Variable with same value for multiple microservices using AddScoped Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to add Correlation ID to request header.If CorrId is not located in the header, then I Created. If it is, I just set it.My problem is sending this header to second micro services. I created Global CorrId class.

```
public class GlobalCorrID
{
    public string CorrID{ get; set; }
}
```

Extension method to register CorrId.

```
public static IServiceCollection CorrId(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    return services.AddScoped<GlobalCorrID, GlobalCorrID>();

}
```

Then I add it for Startup.cs for all microservices.

```
services.CorrId()
```

When the request header comes to the second micro service, my CorrId generated again although it is in same scoped and header includes Corr-Id. If I change class to static, everything works fine. How can I solve this problem?

Btw, I followed [stevejgordon tutorial.](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/asp-net-core-correlation-ids)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add code that will check if CorrelationId already exists in the request and then use it.

You generate a new one only when it not exist in the request.